# converting an irregular table from pdf to csv

Tags: python, pandas, data-conversion, tabula

i have a table in pdf that's like 24 pages long and the table is irregular meaning that there are some empty columns and the design of the table isnt your typical table with borders. currently i have a code that converts all the data correctly but the problem is that it sets it all in one cell and with no spaces. for example if the data had columns firstname, lastname, age,phone,email
it would convert it as janeblack2697412334234janeblack@gmail.com
how do i properly read the data so that each item falls under its corresponding column?

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd
top = 200
left = 54
right = 790
bottom = 560
dfs = tabula.read_pdf(
    "trial.pdf",
    pages='110-111',
    guess=True,
    lattice=False,
    area=(top, left, right, bottom)
)
if len(dfs) == 0:
    print("No tables found in the specified area.")
else:
    # Combine tables into a single DataFrame
    combined_df = pd.concat(dfs)

    column_names = ['distance', 'comment', 'j num', 'c no.','length','wt','feature','time', 'max.','camps','length [mm]','width','location']
    combined_df.columns = column_names

    # Save the combined table as a CSV file
    output_path = "Desktop/test_file.csv"
    combined_df.to_csv(output_path, index=False)
    print("Combined table saved as CSV")
```

Comment: Can you provide an example PDF for testing?